# mysql distinct does not filter unique ids

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql I'm attempting to display the results with a list of devices (serialno) that have not appeared for a specific time (last_seen) and then only display unique devices with the max(last_seen). The last_seen is an init value which is a number that increments (think minutes) when the device has not been seen. Imagine a table that has a row of with serialno "L123" with last_seen "1", then after another minute, serialno "L123" with last_seen "2", and so fourth. Using max(last_seen) the results should display the highest number or the last time the device was seen.

Works so far, but I'm noticing where a device serialno L123 will display twice, how can I filter the results to only display the highest last_seen? I've tried two scenarios using distinct but neither of them seem to work.

As an example of what i get (not working)

```
email             | serialno | Last seen (min)
abc@example.com   | L123     | 30
abc1@example.com  | K900     | 20
abc2@example.com  | L123     | 1 <--yes the email is different but same serialno
```

As an example of what want to see

```
email             | serialno | Last seen (min)
abc@example.com   | L123     | 30
abc1@example.com  | K900     | 20
```

Scenario 1: select distinct in a where sub-query

```
SELECT
    email,
    serialno,
    max(last_seen)

FROM
    my_table

WHERE
    last_seen IN (SELECT last_seen FROM my_table WHERE last_seen > 0)
    AND 
    serialno IN (SELECT distinct serialno FROM my_table)

GROUP BY 
     2,1

ORDER BY 
     3 DESC
```

Scenario 2: using having, after group by

```
SELECT
    email,
    serialno,
    max(last_seen)

FROM
    my_table

WHERE
    last_seen IN (SELECT last_seen FROM my_table WHERE last_seen > 0)

GROUP BY
    2,1

HAVING
    serialno in (SELECT distinct serialno FROM my_table)

ORDER BY
    3 DESC
```

Comment: `group by serialno`...

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: I am, using GROUP BY 1 and the results still show "As an example of what i get (not working)" at the top

Comment: why not just SELECT DISTINCT serialno

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows, i.e. both columns here.

Comment: `group by serialno` ONLY!

Comment: group by column name. This will make it easier to understand later.

Comment: sorry, I made a posting mistake. I have email under select so (email, serialno, max(last_seen) and the GROUP BY is 2,1.

Group by without email does work, but when email is added, it does not.

Comment: Then edit your question!

Comment: sorry, I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` with a sub-query which is used to find each serialno's max last_seen value:

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
join (select serialno, max(Last_seen) Last_seen
      from my_table
      group by serialno) t2
    on t1.serialno = t2.serialno and t1.Last_seen = t2.Last_seen
order by t1.Last_seen desc
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Distinct works on the values you actually want to output. If you use it in a subselect, you must also filter the unique values in the subselect.

Group only by serialno though in the first query. You just want grouped results for your serialno. You don't need a in clause or having.